# How to Send a list of dictionary to cloudwatch using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a list of dictionary that contains, birds and some statistics related to birds

dict=[{'Crow': 24.316, 'Peacock': 0.246, 'Dove': 0.039, 'Sparrow': 0.059, 'Goose': 1.341, 'Ostrich': 3.101, 'Pigeon': 7.202}]

In the documentation this is how we can send the data :

```
    import boto3
import datetime

cloudwatch = boto3.resource('cloudwatch')
metric = cloudwatch.Metric('Namespace', 'MetricName')
metric.put_data(
    Namespace=metric.namespace,
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': metric.metric_name,
            'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            'Value': 1,
            'Unit': 'None',
            'Dimensions': [
                {'Name': 'Environment',
                 'Value': 'SomeValue'
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

Is there a way to send the list of dictionary to cloudwatch so i can retrieve those Value on Cloudwatch ?

Edit :

So to get the key and value of each item on the list of dictionary i'll do it like this:

```
for d in dict:
  for key, value in d.items():
    print(key,value)
```

After that should i include the metric.put_data on the loop ?

Comment: you'll have to format it so that each item in your dictionary is a `MetricData` point.

Comment: Thank you , I will update my question according to your response.

Comment: @gold_cy Thank you for your response i understand it and i think it worked